# Convert dec to hex number in C

Tags: c

I tried to convert dec to hex. For example convert 255 to hex.

`opa = 255.ToString("X");`

gives me error:
error: invalid suffix "ToString" on floating constant

I spent lots of time to convert, but couldn't find right way.

Comment: The question you linked is `C#`. Do you want `C#` to `C`?

Comment: Then copying code from a question on C# won't work; they're completely different languages.

Comment: You need `sprintf()`.

Comment: @Merlin2011 Editing a comment to say something completely different like that is very confusing. It will also stop anyone being notified of your new question.

Comment: @Ben I read that one, but it only outputs as hex, I want to assign that value as hex to another variable.

Comment: The question doesn't even make sense. 255 is a *number*, and numbers aren't decimal or hexadecimal. They're just numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're asking about the wrong language. C does not support the dot operator on integers. To do this in C, you need to print it to a string like so.

```
char numstr[10];
sprintf(numstr, "%X", 255)
```

Comment: On a side note, numstr is string type, but I wanted it to be integer type, so I can do calculations with it.

Comment: If it's an integer, it's an integer. Whether it's dec of hex is just how you print it.